# addClass css animation laggy

Tags: jquery, css, animation, lag, toggleclass

I have a very basic js script to toggle my css class that changes the background of the entire page. The code works but when the background changes the animation is choppy and looks terrible. I checked the image res and file size and the images are only around 100KB, i even tried with a base64 encode as well but both are choppy. Below is some of the code, hopefully someone can tell me why its so choppy.

Here is a link to a jsfiddle with the exact code but with the image urls replaced with colors. for some reason the animation doesn't work in fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/ouu762ho/2/

CSS:

```
.container{
    background:url(images/4.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;    
    -webkit-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.home-click{
    background-image:url(images/3.jpg);
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
    transition: background 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".home").click(function(){
        $(".container").toggleClass("home-click", 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is '1000' your second toggleClass argument? It should be a boolean to indicate state. Anyway, try being more specific in your transform property list - i.e., background-size instead of background. Secondly, you can also try using the 'will-change' css property to reserve resources for the image transition. However, be responsible about how many elements you use will-change on.

Comment: Did you try caching the image first?

Comment: Additionally, you don't need to set a duration on toggleClass if you're doing the animation using css.

Comment: In your fiddle you forgot to add jQuery and you had `background-image: #ccc` instead of `background-color` in your `.home-click` class. Here's a corrected fiddle, though the animation is smooth when you're only dealing with colours. Can you provide us with some image URLs?  http://jsfiddle.net/ouu762ho/2/

Comment: Which browser is causing issues? I updated the fiddle with some images, and the animation is smooth: http://jsfiddle.net/ouu762ho/3/ (Chrome)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses! I removed the 1000 after the toggle in the js. I refined the background calls in CSS and attempted a will-change but nothing there helped. I'm running the server locally so i dont think caching is the the issue. I did update the jsfiddle page with Stef's fixed version (Thanks!). I am having the issue in chrome, I tried your jsfiddle out Jack and it worked fine! I think it might be the images because I uploaded what I had to my free hosting account and got the same results.